# Авторизация В вконтакте

Tags: авторизация, php, вконтакте

Как понять где авторизовался?
Есть такая авторизация:

```
$TEXTlogin = 'Логин';
$TEXTpass = 'Пароль';
    $auth = file_get_contents('http://login.vk.com/
    act=login&amp;email='.$TEXTlogin.'&amp;pass='.$TEXTpass);
    if (preg_match('/hash=([a-z0-9]{1,32})/', $auth, $hash)) {
    $url= 'http://vk.com/login.php?act=slogin&amp;role=fast&amp;redirect=1&amp;to=&amp;s=1&amp;<strong>__q_hash=</strong>' . $hash[1];
    $res = file_get_contents($url);
    preg_match('/remixsid=(.*?);/', $res, $sid);
    $cookie = 'remixdt=-3600; remixlang=0; audio_vol=100; remixseenads=2; remixflash=11.4.402; remixsid=' . $sid[1];
    // Тут Авторизовался что ли?    
    } 
    else {
    // А тут нет?
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Судя по всему, - да

```
if (preg_match('/hash=([a-z0-9]{1,32})/', $auth, $hash)) {
// Всё получилось
} else {
// Ошибка
}
```